# Nested Loop to show results on same row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have stored procedure to generate a results like following

[image]

I want to show a result like following

which is

```
if (HeaderID and TitleNo same) 
show that results in same row 

else
 go to new row
```

[image]

So I wrote the Razor page like following

```
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2" class="vertaline-mid">@item.TitleNo</td>
                                    <td rowspan="2" class="vertaline-mid">@item.TitleImage</td>

                                    @foreach (var image in Model)
                                    {
                                        <td class="image-td">
                                            <a>@image.SubtitleName</a>
                                            <span>@image.SubtitleValue</span>
                                        </td>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @foreach (var imageid in Model)
                                    {
                                        <td>@imageid.CaseID</td>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            }                               
                        </tbody>
```

But then I'm getting view like following which is wrong

I cant even Group this stored procedure then that will be effect on some result.

how to handle this on client side.

[image]

Comment: Use a `.GroupBy()` to group you data by `HeaderID` and `TitleNo` and project it into a view model that you pass to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I have detailed example

Comment: Busy now - will be 30 min or so.

Comment: @StephenMuecke oky thanku , here the query and model class I'm using https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/8oGAB

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is there should be any enhancement on ModelClass to follow the way you said ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first group your data by `HeaderID` and `TitleN`o and project it into a view model(s) that represent what you need to display.

View Model (rename these to relate to your data)

```
public class ParentVM
{
    public string TitleNo { get; set; }
    public int TitleImage { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildVM> SubTitles {  get; set; }
}
public class ChildVM
{
    public string SubtitleName { get; set; }
    public string SubTitleValue { get; set; }
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
}
```

and the the query will be

```
var model = yourContext.GroupBy(x => new { x.TitleNo, x.HeaderID }).Select(x => new ParentVM
{
    TitleNo = x.Key.TitleNo,
    TitleImage = x.FirstOrDefault().TitleImage,
    SubTitles = x.Select(y => new ChildVM
    {
        SubtitleName = y.SubtitleName,
        SubTitleValue = y.SubTitleValue,
        CaseID = y.CaseID,
    })
});
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ParentVM>
....
<table>
    @foreach(var parent in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@parent.TitleNo </td>
            <td>@parent.TitleImage</td>
            @foreach(var child in parent.SubTitles)
            {
                <td>
                    <div>@child.SubtitleName</div>
                    <div>@child.SubTitleValue</div>
                    <div>@child.CaseID</div>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Is that , In your linq query `ChildVM`, `ParentVM`  should be inside the `VM` Model Class ?

Comment: Sorry, Had a couple of typo's in the query - see edit

Comment: Note that I was not sure about `TitleImage` and if for each `HeaderID` and `TitleNo` group you could have more that one value. If so you would need `.GroupBy(x => new { x.TitleNo, x.HeaderID, x.TitleImage }) {` and use `TitleImage = x.Key.TitleImage,` to set it

Comment: You could also enhance this by having a `int SubTitlesCount` property and set it using `SubTitlesCount= y.Count(),` and then use it to generate empty `<td>` elements so that each table row has the same number of `<td>` elements (you would also need to calculate and pass the max number to the view

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq group function. 
I am now in air port, so i can not guarantee the codes is fully correct but the idea is this

```
@foreach(var g in Model.GroupBy(m=>m.TitleNo){
<tr>
<td>@g.Key</td>
<td>
<td>
@foreach(var gi in g){whatever codes you need to display}
</td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try this

Comment: How to groupby with two values

Comment: separate property with ','   like =>m.TitileNo, m.HeaderID. and you need use g.Key.TitleNo to access the specific group key

Comment: its not listing as g.Key.TitleNo :(